# where do I find bidirectional_rnn in tensorflow 1.0.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using some code from here: https://github.com/monikkinom/ner-lstm with tensorflow. I think the code was written for an older version of tensorflow, I am using version 1.0.0. I used tf_upgrade.py to upgrade model.py in that github repos, but I am still getting the error:

```
    output, _, _ = contrib_rnn.bidirectional_rnn(fw_cell, bw_cell,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bidirectional_rnn'
```

this is after I changed the bidirectional_rnn call to use contrib_rnn which is:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops import core_rnn as contrib_rnn
```

The old call was

```
 output, _, _ = tf.nn.bidirectional_rnn(fw_cell, bw_cell,
                                               tf.unpack(tf.transpose(self.input_data, perm=[1, 0, 2])),
                                               dtype=tf.float32, sequence_length=self.length)
```

which also doesn't work.

I had to change the LSTMCell, DroputWrapper, etc. to rnn.LSTMCell, but they seem to work fine. It is the bidirectional_rnn that I can't figure out how to change.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to reimplement a bidirectional RNN by simply wrapping into a single class two monodirectional RNNs with the parameter "go_backwards=True" set on one of them. Then you can also have control over the type of merge done with the outputs. Maybe taking a look at the implementation in https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/wrappers.py (see the class `Bidirectional`) could get you started.

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow 1.0, you have the choice of two bidirectional RNN functions:

- [`tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/bidirectional_dynamic_rnn)
- [`tf.contrib.rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/static_bidirectional_rnn)

Comment: static link is dead